# My Nvidia GPU is not being used on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I recently noticed that my Nvidia 1080ti was not being used by Ubuntu. I checked using the command `ubuntu-drivers devices`as well as `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and determined that the recommended driver was installed. It also shows as selected in the GUI "additional Drivers" tab in the Software & Updates application. Unfortunately, when I checked the About tab in settings it shows that the recommended Nvidia driver is not being used and it is using llvmpipe instead. The recommended Nvidia driver is the 530 driver; I'm unsure how to make Ubuntu use the Nvidia Driver. As a side note, I was able to install Nouveau and get that working so it seems to be an issue with the 530 driver. I have also installed and run `hwinfo --gfxcard` which game the the results below.

```
20: PCI 700.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: aK5u.oBefySgvKLF
  Parent ID: w+J7.wfd8oV4+v2B
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:07:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1b06 "GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x3607 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "nouveau"
  Driver Modules: "nouveau"
  Memory Range: 0xfb000000-0xfbffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xe0000000-0xe1ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe07f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xfc000000-0xfc07ffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 79 (68215 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00001B06sv00001462sd00003607bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #6 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #20
```

I've also attached a few images. Any help is appreciated.

[image: System Info]
[image: Additional Drivers Tab]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that's normal for nVidia driver in on-demand mode to use integrated videocard instead under light load.

You can run `nvidia-settings` and select Performance in PRIME profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, there is no PRIME option in the nvidia-settings app. I don't have integrated graphics in my computer just the 1080ti.

Comment: @ChaseSimmons Try this command for clarity `hwinfo --gfxcard` what drivers are available and what is used. But that's quite old graphics card, do you have any specific reason to use nVidia driver instead of open-source one? Also worth checking if nvidia driver isn't blacklisted on your system.

Comment: llvmpipe is CPU rendering, not integrated GPU rendering

Comment: I was trying to use the Nvidia drivers for better performance but it seems like they stopped working. I've been using the open-source one for now and it seems to work fine. I just want to figure out why the proprietary drivers are not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the proprietary Nvida Driver working after installing the Nouveau open source driver, restarting, uninstalling the "Nvidia X Server Settings" app, using the computer for 10-15 minutes,restarting, reinstalling the Nvidia driver, and then restarting. I'm not sure how it fixed it but it did.

I hope this helps anyone else experiencing similar issues.

P.S. The Nouveau driver works fine for productivity not for games.

In short:

1. Install the Nouveau open-source driver.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Uninstall the "Nvidia X Server Settings" app
4. Use the computer for 10-15 minutes.
5. Restart the computer.
6. Install the Nvidia driver (530 in my case)
7. Restart the computer.
8. The Nvidia driver should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was running

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and rebooting

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343348)